# how to figure out which variable to use on the basis of weight?

Tags: math

Let's say I have 5 variables v1, v2, v3, v4, v5 with weights as follows:

```
v1 = 30
v2 = 20
v3 = 10
v4 = 25
v5 = 15
```

I want some formula which if i run 100 times will yield v1 30 times, v2 20 times, v3 10 times, v4 25 times, v5 15 times.

Note: The order of variables should be random.

Context:
We are going to run some parallel campaigns on our site. Weight will be assigned to each campaign to specify the percentage of sessions a campaign should be displayed in e.g. to perform an A/B testing, admin will specify 50 weight for campaign 1 and 50 weight for campaign 2.

Comment: This isn't clear. Are you trying to *randomize* the vi?

Comment: Pardon me for not being clear. Yes, I want the variables to come in random order.

Comment: No real *formula* for this. Why not just form an array/list of length 100 consisting of 30 v2, 20 v2, etc. and then shuffle the array? In Python that could be done in about 3 lines of code.

Comment: Yes. It came to my mind. But i was wondering if there was some nicer way to accomplish this.

Comment: The nicest way to accomplish it is probably dependent upon which programming language you are using, but the question is stated in a language-independent way.

Comment: Language is Ruby. I intentionally stated it in language-independent way to lay stress on Math formula.

Comment: The solution is not a "math formula", it's an "algorithm". The algorithm is so simple that its language-independent description fits in @JohnColeman 's one-line comment. If all you want is the algorithm, there you have it. If you want the "best" or "shorter" or "most efficient" implementation of that algorithm in a particular language, then ask for that language explicitly.